# How do I unlock device from ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, without using KeyguardManager?

Tags: android

KeyguardManager has been deprecated.

What code am I now supposed to use,
to unlock the device from an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2,
before running the test ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the Window object from this code? If yes, you can turn on keyguard like this:

```
getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
```

and then turn off keyguard like this:

```
getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I get:
"java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission"  , 

with your suggestion and all relevant permission flags (FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and friends) set on the window.

I think it's not possible (or ever was possible even with the KeyGuardManager)  
to unlock the device from code. So the question is meaningless. It stems from me confusing a locked screen with a guarded screen.

The solution is to disable the keyguard while developing.

Comment: I misunderstood your original question. Never mind this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is meaningless.
It stems from me confusing a locked screen with a guarded screen.
The solution is to disable the keyguard/keylock while developing.